# SwiftUI - How to make Image capInsets work so that image is not stretched?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "bubble.right")
            .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    }
}
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Here is the result

[image]

You can see that the image is still badly stretched. How can i get capInsets working?

**[Edit 1]** -

What I want is to have a bubble image that can increase in width and height. But I do not want the the image to look distorted upon stretching. Using CapInsets, I am supposed to prevent this.

Comment: This code is crashing. You set the image width 2x of its height. May be thats the reason.

Comment: Your comment is not clear. Whatever you will do with this given code, unless you set the edgeInsets correctly, it will crash. Your code crashed on runtime.

Comment: I added an update. Let me know if this is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the best results, your edge insets should leave a "1x1 pixel" area in the center of the image; this will then upon resizing just repeat the middle row and column of the image.

So you need something like

```
EdgeInsets(top:centerY-1.0, leading:centerY-1.0, bottom:centerY, trailing:centerX)
```

where `centerX` and `centerY` refer to the original image size (which you need to calculate somehow)

### Update

If you use assets, you could slice the image there directly, so you can omit the EdgeInsets:
First, press "Show Slicing":
[image]

Then, perform the slicing ("Start Slicing", then the "double arrow"), resulting in something like this:
[image]

Comment: sounds like it can work. Any ideas on how to calculate midpoint?

Comment: Either get it from the image, or - if you use the image from an asset catalog - you could slice it there (at the right bottom, there is a "show slicing" button, then press "start slicing")

Comment: you are correct, but i believe that my problem was that my image was not vector PDF. So it was being stretched.

Comment: for me I had to remove the whole .resizable() line for it to work with slicing in the image catalog